# Eclipse RCP - conditionally displaying menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rich-client-platform

I am working on an Eclipse RCP product (based on Eclipse 3.6) which has multiple applications/plugins.
Following is the use case in which I have got stuck:
There are 3 plugins A, B and C. I need to display a menu contribution in "Edit" menu in plugins A and B (not in C), only when plugin C is installed. If plugin C is not installed the menu contribution should not be displayed - not even in a disabled state.
On doing some search I found that there is a property tester which can determine if a plugin is installed - it is to be used as:

```
<with variable="platform">
    <test property="org.eclipse.core.runtime.isBundleInstalled" args="com.mybundle"/>
</with>
```

However when i tried it didn't work for me.
I am not sure if use of this property is relevant in the context that I am trying to use it in. Can somebody help?
If the codeless option is not viable then I will have to show/hide the menu contribution programmatically but I do not know where this should ideally be done.
Should I write a PerspectiveListener for plugins A and B and add the menu contribution in case of `PerspectiveActivated` after verifying that C is installed?

Please help.

Thanks and regards,
Pradyumna

Comment: Didn't work in what way?  It was always displayed?  Or never displayed?

Comment: @Paul - it was never displayed. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

I had made a mistake because of which `isBundleInstalled` was not working. The variable `platform` was not available and hence I did not get the expected output. Replacing it with `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` did the trick.